# python 3.2: pygame.KEYDOWN works only 1 time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

there is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *
from time import sleep
import os

path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(path + '\Assets')

pygame.init()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('fightR')

WHITE = (225, 225, 225)
SILVER = (192, 192, 192)
BGCOLOR = SILVER
fkx = 70
fky = 252
SPEED = 5
jump = False

#loading images
fighter_kungfu_1 = pygame.image.load('fighter_kungfu_1.png')
fighter_kungfu_jump = pygame.image.load('fighter_kungfu_jump.png')

def CheckForQuit() :
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()

#MGL
while True:

    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
            if (fkx > 2):        
                 global fkx
                 fkx = fkx - SPEED
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d:
            if (fkx < 300):
                global fkx
                fkx = fkx + SPEED
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        jump = True

if (jump):
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(fighter_kungfu_jump, (fkx - 25, fky - 10))
    #sleep(0.5)
else:
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(fighter_kungfu_1, (fkx, fky))

jump = False

CheckForQuit()

pygame.display.update()
fpsClock.tick(FPS)
pygame.display.flip()
```

a link to the images if you want:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Aq1fJx1P4AQkE1ZTZLR1ZCRW8
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Aq1fJx1P4AeXB5UjYtZ29XU1k
(put them in an 'Assets' folder)

my problem with the game: when i press the 'a' or the 'd' button and hold it, my character moves only one time instead of moving continually.

i have tried to put a "while" loop instead of the "if" and the "elif":

```
while event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
    if (fkx > 2):
         global fkx
         fkx = fkx - SPEED
while event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d:
    if (fkx < 300):
         global fkx
         fkx = fkx + SPEED
```

but it isn't working at all.

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event only occurs when the key moves from unpressed to pressed, which you are only doing once.

If you want to track which keys are depressed, you could set a flag when you receive the keydown event, and then unset it when you receive the keyup event.

Alternatively, you could use the `get_pressed` function (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to get the current state of the keyboard keys.

You could also look at setting how keydown events are repeated with https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat . However, I believe that setting flags on the various events is the best solution, followed by checking for key state as a second best option.